# RoboVm and App Store Review Guidelines

Tags: java, ios, xcode

I will develop an App using eclipse and roboVM. In the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) at point 2.8 is written: *Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected.*
RoboVM launch my Java Code. Is that allowed?

best regards Londi

P.s. sorry for my english ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no idea if this is "allowed" or not but I can tell you right now that there are tons off application made with RoboVM on the appstore. Seven of them belongs to me so you should be completely fine!